# Java server multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, client-server

How to implement a multi-threaded server in Java? where the server listens for a port (for example 5000) and serves the connection in a separate thread and keeps listening for more clients.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a typical example:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

while(true)
{
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    Runnable r = new TaskImplementsRunnable(s);
    executor.submit(r)
}
```

```
public class TaskImplementsRunnable implements Runnable
{
    private Socket socket;

    public TaskImplementsRunnable(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String command;
            while((command = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("command 1"))
                {
                    writer.println("This is command 1!");
                }
                else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("command 2"))
                {
                    writer.println("This is command 2!");
                }
                else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    writer.println("This is unknown command!");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            writer.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```