# muilti threading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

so what i am trying to do is write a server and a client. the server should listen for a connection and service that connection on a differ thread and keep listening for more client. once connected the client will send over the IP  it wished the server to resolve. the server sould write this back the the client. this is what i got so far... how do i make the server better. and how to write the client
How do you write the client file to connect to this and send it the ip they want.

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintStream;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;

public class Server implements Runnable {
Socket csocket;
Server(Socket csocket) {
  this.csocket = csocket;
 }

public static void main(String args[]) 
throws Exception {
   ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(6053);
   System.out.println("Listening");
   while (true) {
      Socket sock = ssock.accept();
      System.out.println("Connected");
     new Thread(new Server(sock)).start();
   }
}
public void run() {
   try {
      PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream
      (csocket.getOutputStream());

      pstream.close();
      csocket.close();
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: This code looks fine so far.  What's the problem?

Comment: You asked this question already not a half hour ago; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350720/java-server-multithreading

Comment: [I updated my answer on the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15350754/597657).

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is make it for "user friendly", i have done this thing before and made a successful IM program.

ideas:

1. make it able to get global IP
2. display a handshake (if connected = true){ system.out.print( has connected!);}

Comment: I dont know how to write the client file

Comment: that is the main problem.. Sorry i was not clear on that

Comment: yes i did do again but i need the client, and i wrote my code diffidently.