# Keeping a (single threaded) server socket listening for clients on unexpected socket closure

Tags: java, sockets

How should one deal with clients disconnecting unexpectedly. I want to keep the server running/listening unless explicitly stated to close by the client.

For example, my server is listening and then the client is closed which causes the server's method to end - how can I get it to return to the beginning of the method as it were?

```
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();         
    out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));                   
    BasicProtocol bp = new BasicProtocol(password);
    out.println(bp.processInput(""));
    String inputLine;
    while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ){
       System.out.println("Client asks: " + inputLine);
       out.println(bp.processInput(inputLine));            
    }
```

As above, if a connection reset error occurs how can it wait to be reconnected to?

Comment: See this example: [`Typical Multi-threaded server`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15350754/597657)

Comment: 'which causes the server's method to end' - How does it do that? What does your exception-handling code look like?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad so you must have multi-threading to deal with this?

Comment: By putting that code into a loop, obviously. The fact that the server is single threaded is the only other problem here.

Comment: It is pretty obvious isn't it? But that's the answer, sometimes simple things pass your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance you can have a while loop at the method with a boolean variable that is changed when the client wants to close. As such:

```
boolean isRunning = true;
while (isRunning) {
    //Your current method - when client wants to disconnect just set isRunning = false;
}
```