# Java Threading within TCP and server sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I have written the following two lines

```
ServerSocket mobCom = new ServerSocket(9846);
Socket server = mobCom.accept();
```

I want a new TCP connection to be created and that connection to be handled by a new thread. For example the above code creates a server socket. And there are multiple clients. Whenever a client connects to a server a new thread may be created that will cater to requests coming from that particular client. How do I implement the same.

**EDIT**

I also want to limit a thread pool to 10 users. And if more users arise I want to send them an error message without processing further requests from them.

Comment: There are about a million examples of this on the net...

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15350754/597657).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired results using the java util concurrent's [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html).
Create a fixed number of workers. Use the **take** call to initiate block read onto the SynchronousQueue. So if all the workers have taken one work each and are busy processing them (communicating with the socket), there will be none reading from the SynchronousQueue and hence an **offer** to synchronous queue will fail. Checking this failure (which means all fixed number workers are busy, none latching onto the queue now), reject the next request(s).

Sample code in following lines [Untested - Avoided exceptions for brevity, please amend to your need].

```
public class BoundedServer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /**
         * Port to serve
         */
        final int port = 2013;

        /**
         * Max Workers
         */
        final int maxworkers = 10; 

        /**
         * The server socket.
         */
        ServerSocket mServerSocket = null;

        /**
         * Queue of work units to process if there is a worker available.
         */
        final SynchronousQueue<WorkUnit> mQueueToProcess = new SynchronousQueue<WorkUnit>();

        /**
         * Queue of work units to reject if there is no current worker available.
         */
        final LinkedBlockingQueue<WorkUnit> mQueueToReject = new LinkedBlockingQueue<WorkUnit>(); 

        /**
         * A thread pool to handle the work.
         */
        final ExecutorService communicationservice = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxworkers);

        /**
         * Let a single thread take care of rejecting the requests when needed to do so.
         */
        final ExecutorService rejectionservice = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        try 
        {
            Runnable communicationlauncher = new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        /**
                         * Set of workers to handle the work.
                         */
                        final CommunicationWorker[] workers = new CommunicationWorker[maxworkers];

                        communicationservice.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(workers));
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        communicationservice.shutdown();
                    }
                }
            };

            new Thread(communicationlauncher).start();

            Runnable rejectionlauncher = new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        RejectionWorker rejectionworker = new RejectionWorker(mQueueToReject);

                        rejectionservice.submit(rejectionworker);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        rejectionservice.shutdown();
                    }
                }
            };
            new Thread(rejectionlauncher).start();

            mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

            while(true)
            {
                WorkUnit work = new WorkUnit(mServerSocket.accept());

                if(!mQueueToProcess.offer(work))
                {
                    mQueueToReject.add(work);
                }
            }
        } 
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                mServerSocket.close();
            }
        }
    }
}


public class WorkUnit 
{
    private Socket mSocket = null;

    public WorkUnit(Socket socket) 
    {
        super();
        this.setSocket(socket);
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }

    public void setSocket(Socket mSocket) {
        this.mSocket = mSocket;
    }
}

public class CommunicationWorker 
implements Callable<Boolean> 
{
    private SynchronousQueue<WorkUnit> mQueueToProcess;

    public CommunicationWorker(SynchronousQueue<WorkUnit> queueToProcess) 
    {
        super();
        this.mQueueToProcess = queueToProcess;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception 
    {
        while(true)
        {
            WorkUnit work = mQueueToProcess.take();

            Socket socket = work.getSocket();

            // Code to handle socket communication and closure.
            // Once the communication is finished, this thread will get blocked to mQueueToProcess.
        }
    }
}


public class RejectionWorker 
implements Callable<Boolean> 
{
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<WorkUnit> mQueueToReject;

    public RejectionWorker(LinkedBlockingQueue<WorkUnit> queueToReject) 
    {
        super();
        this.mQueueToReject = queueToReject;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception 
    {
        while(true)
        {
            WorkUnit work = mQueueToReject.take();

            Socket socket = work.getSocket();

            // Code to reject the request.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to do something like following. ServiceThread is thread will service requests.

```
 while (true) {
              try {
                  Socket clientSocket = null;
                  if (null != serverSocket) {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    ServiceThread serverThread = new ServiceThread(clientSocket); // Create a new thread for each client
                    serverThread.start();
                  }
              }  catch( Exception ex ) {
                  System.out.println("Exception while accepting connection " + ex.getMessage());
                  ex.printStackTrace();
              }
```

Comment: This code will smoke the CPU if `serverSocket` is null.